# Register partials in express-handlebars

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I'm trying to register my partials into my app. I cannot figure it out how to do so. No matter what answer I get from other stack questions, it just don't work for me...

I set the express handlebars

```
import { engine } from 'express-handlebars';

//I use modules so without this(don't know what it does) doesn't work
const __filename = new URL(import.meta.url).pathname;
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);

app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
app.set('views', './views');
app.engine('hbs', engine({
    extname: '.hbs',
    partialsDir: path.join(__dirname, 'views', 'partials')
}));
```

I have the following dir format:
[image]

I create my layout format and import the body and header:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>{{title}}</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
</head>
<body>
    {{> header }}

    {{{body}}}

</body>
</html>
```

Than, in the partials folder I create the header :

```
<header>
    <p>Wellcome back back</p>
</header>
```

After all this, my app doesn't find the partials name header:

```
Error: The partial header could not be found
    at Object.invokePartial (C:\Users\sasda\Desktop\websockets\node_modules\handlebars\dist\cjs\handlebars\runtime.js:332:11)
    at Object.invokePartialWrapper [as invokePartial] (C:\Users\sasda\Desktop\websockets\node_modules\handlebars\dist\cjs\handlebars\runtime.js:84:39)
    at Object.eval [as main] (eval at createFunctionContext (C:\Users\sasda\Desktop\websockets\node_modules\handlebars\dist\cjs\handlebars\compiler\javascript-compiler.js:262:23), <anonymous>:13:28)
    at main (C:\Users\sasda\Desktop\websockets\node_modules\handlebars\dist\cjs\handlebars\runtime.js:208:32)
    at ret (C:\Users\sasda\Desktop\websockets\node_modules\handlebars\dist\cjs\handlebars\runtime.js:212:12)
    at ret (C:\Users\sasda\Desktop\websockets\node_modules\handlebars\dist\cjs\handlebars\compiler\compiler.js:519:21)
    at ExpressHandlebars._renderTemplate (C:\Users\sasda\Desktop\websockets\node_modules\express-handlebars\dist\express-handlebars.js:244:16)
    at ExpressHandlebars.<anonymous> (C:\Users\sasda\Desktop\websockets\node_modules\express-handlebars\dist\express-handlebars.js:156:31)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (C:\Users\sasda\Desktop\websockets\node_modules\express-handlebars\dist\express-handlebars.js:10:58)
```

Comment: Take a look at this example https://github.com/express-handlebars/express-handlebars/blob/master/examples/advanced/server.js#L12

Comment: Your code looks fine and works locally for me. `The partial xxx could not be found` typically means there is no file named `header.hbs` in the `views/partials` directory. I know you posted an image of your folder structure but in my experience 9/10 times there is a spelling mistake, extra character or space in the name - either in your code or the file. Create a brand new `header.hbs` and copy the header code into it. Delete the old one. Save and  restart your server.

Comment: There is a problem with the path.join. When I set `app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));` in the express app.js folder, node simply dont find my views now. But when I write the relative path, `app.set('views', './views');` node have no problem... Never encounter this before

Comment: Where is this file (your main file) in relation to the views folder? Can you post your full project folder? Also, how are you importing `path` module?

Comment: My main file is in a subdirectory of views: 
`views/layouts/main.hbs`. I will post the full app.js file. I found also a solving, but I dont know why it works now.

Answer (score 0):

I used modules to import in JS files:

```
{
  "name": "websockets",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "module": "true",
  "type": "module",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon server.js"
  },
```

So far, I tried to use path with imports module. It gave me errors like the following:

```
file:///C:/Users/sasda/Desktop/websockets/app.js:23
app.use(expres.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
                                ^

ReferenceError: __dirname is not defined in ES module scope
This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and 'C:\Users\sasda\Desktop\websockets\package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.
```

I tried luckily to just write hardcode the path with `./views/partials`, or whatever I needed to import in my app.js.
Later on I found the following helpers.

```
const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = dirname(__filename);
```

I don't understand why it works, but finally I am able to use partials and views without hardcode the paths:

```
import { create } from 'express-handlebars';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import { dirname } from 'path';



const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = dirname(__filename);

/**
 *  Serve and set the handlebars engine
*/
app.use(expres.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

const hbs = create({
    extname:        '.hbs',
    partialsDir:    path.join(__dirname, 'views', 'partials'),
    layoutsDir:     path.join(__dirname, 'views', 'layouts')
});
app.engine('hbs', hbs.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
```

My folder structure is remaining unchanged:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Don't think you need to set the views twice, I have it once and it works fine. Try setting your engine and the handlebars like this. Try switching the order that you are running app.engine and app.set:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KCuf.png)